# JavaScript not executed before PDF gets generated

Tags: javascript

Using Entity Print 8x-2.1, I've got everything working great (thanks to the developoers of that module) except it does not appear to support loading the javascript portion of attached libraries. CSS is loading and rendering as expected from my print_styling library, but the custom.js below is not only not executing, it doesn't even appear to be loaded when I check "sources" under chrome's developer tools from the entity print /debug page.  When I look in the code, it doesn't appear to even try loading js assets.  Am I right that entity print is punting on loading js, or is it possibly just an issue with the base url? If js support is not yet implemented in entity_print, is just a matter of needing someone to develop it, or is there a fundamental limitation that prevents using js with wkhtmlpdf and entity_print? It appears so from my reading of the wkhtmltopdf docs that it could support js, though it needs a config setting for the javascript-delay to make sure execution completes before the pdf is generated.

```
print_styling:
  css:
    theme:
      css/print2.css: {}
  js:
    js/custom.js: {}
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Sorry, I have to ask a dumb question: Are you expecting JS in your PDF? Or what exactly is the issue? Can you please edit your question for clarification? Many thanks

Comment: Ah you expect JS to be executed before the PDF is generated. I don't think that any PDF converter library supports that. But I may be wrong. I'd suggest you'd rather open a support request issue in the module's issue queue.

Comment: Thank you, yes I'm wanting javascript defined in drupal libraries, to execute prior to the pdf being generated. wkhtmltopdf seems to include some settings such as --debug-javascript, --javascript-delay, etc that suggests it supports execution of javascript prior to pdf generation, but I think the js libraries are not being included in the render process in the entity_print code.  I will post in the module issue queue.